# jquery cycle uncover effect change direction or custom effect

Tags: jquery-cycle

I would like to change the direction of uncover fx depending on the active slide index and the next slide index.

The effect I want to get is like: http://www.shegy.nazwa.pl/test2/ - here it works like charm but with scroll and in jquery cycle I would like to have navigation menu to jump to particular slide.

I know that there is something like scrollVert - but its not the same.

Anybody could give a little advice?